# Switch from a JPanel to another JPanel and then back again

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

SOLVED thanks to @camickr

I have built a game using a JFrame and JPanels. The game all works fine but I wanted to add a screen in between levels to let the user know they have completed the level they are on and the next one is loading. 
The code should switch to one JPanel, wait for a second and then switch back again to the origional with the new level loaded. I am using a CardLayout to swap between screens and have tried waiting using a swing timer and Thread.sleep(), but when I run the code the JPanel between levels is never displayed. I think the compiler is running all the code in the method and sees that is should end back on the original JPanel and so never displays the level complete JPanel.

I have created an MVCE below that highlights the issue:

```
package testjpanelexample;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestJPanelExample {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    TestJPanelExample test = new TestJPanelExample("Test");
}
private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
private final JFrame gameWindow;
private final TestDrawingPanel myDrawingPanel;
private final TestStartGame startGame;
private final JPanel cards;
private final CardLayout cl1;
private static final String DRAWINGPANEL = "DrawingPanel";
private static final String STARTGAME = "StartGame";

//creates a JFrame and all the JPanels and adds them to a CardLayout
public TestJPanelExample(String title)
{               
    gameWindow = new JFrame(title);
    gameWindow.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    startGame = new TestStartGame(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    startGame.addAL(new StartButton());
    myDrawingPanel = new TestDrawingPane(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    gameWindow.add(cards);
    cards.add(startGame, STARTGAME);
    cards.add(myDrawingPanel, DRAWINGPANEL);
    cl1 = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    gameWindow.setVisible(true);
    gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


//starts the game running
public void startTheGame()
{
    cl1.show(cards, DRAWINGPANEL);
    update();
}

//switches back to the start screen    
public void update()
{
    cl1.show(cards, STARTGAME);
}    

//an action listener to be added to the start screen
private class StartButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {           
            startTheGame();
    }
}


//The opening screen
class TestStartGame extends JPanel 
{

private JPanel buttons;
public  JButton start;

//creates a JPanel with a single button to start the game    
public TestStartGame(int width, int height)
{
    setSize(width, height);
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    start = new JButton("Start");
    add(start);
}            

//adds an action listener to the button    
public void addAL(ActionListener al)
{
    start.addActionListener(al);
}   
}

//The game screen (currently just a blank blue screen)
class TestDrawingPanel extends JPanel{

//creates the drawing panel 
public TestDrawingPanel(int width, int height)
{                
    setSize(width, height);
    this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
}      
} 
}
```

If the update method is not called then myDrawingPanel is displayed as a blank cyan screen. But if the update method is called then the screen just stays on the start screen. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `The code should switch to one JPanel, wait for a second and then switch back again to the origional with the new level loaded.` - Then you need to use a `Swing Timer`. Don't use Thread.sleep(). Your `MCVE` doesn't show your Timer logic, so we can't guess what you might have done wrong. Basically the logic to be to switch to the temporary panel. Then you start the Timer. When the Timer fires you switch back to the game panel.

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to use one Timer to do two things, but needed a second Timer to make it work. Many thanks.